# Fastest simple way to render a .obj/.blend with UV mapped texture to .png

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a UV mapped texture image in an `io.BytesIO` object and a .obj/.blend file I want to render this texture onto. I can view and render it in Blender, but I'm not sure how to render it to another `io.BytesIO` object in .png format with only a Python script (ie, without using the Blender GUI) in the quickest way possible. Is this possible?